# Why typedef to a function is required, while casting void* to function pointer?

Tags: c++, casting, function-pointers

I was using dlsym() to load a function symbol

```
void (*func)(int);
func = (func*)dlsym(phandle, "function");
```

This was resulting in compilation error.
However, when I did typedef to function

```
 typedef void (*func)(int);
 func function = null;
 function = (func*)dlsym(phandle, "function");
```

This compiled fine, but I fail to understand, why it was failing in first case?
Could anyone please tell the reason?
I read that C++ standard doesnt allow direct casting from void* to function pointer?
Why is this and how did typedef solved this problem?

Comment: What is the compilation error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It fails in the first case because `func` is a variable, not a type, and cannot be used in a cast.

Note the `*` is misplaced:

```
typedef void (*func)(int);
           /* ^ must be here. */
```

Answer (score 3):

Casting  between `void *` and function pointers is prohibited because it's hard to implement on some platforms.

There are computers (see [Harvard architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_architecture)) where code and data reside in physically different memories. So, just because you have a pointer to some data, that doesn't mean it makes sense to magially convert that to a pointer to code.

That's why casting to/from `void *` and functions is not allowed. Sure, on most modern/typical CPUs (by which I mean machines using a [von Neumann architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_architecture), *not* Harvard), the cast will work.

Comment: Oh, So you mean for me it worked, but this might not work in some other architecture?

Comment: @yogeshsingh Yes, converting function pointers to/from `void *` is not portable, at all.